# Why cedilla-portuguese.sh is in default /etc/porfile.d/ list?

Tags: bash, scripts, autostart, locale

I never used or selected Portuguese  locales, either had any connection to Portugal or Brazil, so why we have these scripts running every interactive bash running?

Answer (score 0):

Because it helps those affected as explained in the file.

It needs to belong to some package, and *language-selector-common* appeared to be suitable. The time it takes to run that test is negligible.